# How to delete an element at specific index in dynamic array in C language?

Tags: c

I have a dynamic array of structs declared this way:

```
struct RECORD *records = NULL;
struct RECORD *records_temp;
int records_size = 0;

struct RECORD {
    char *name;
    char *number;
};
```

I need a function that deletes element at given index. Right now I have this:

```
int remove(struct RECORD *array, int size, int index) {
    int toMove = size - index - 1;
    memmove(&array[index], &array[index + 1], toMove * sizeof(array[0]));
    return size - 1;
}
```

It works, but I'm almost certain that it causes segmentation fault (I can't reliably reproduce it, however, which makes it extremely hard to debug).

Is there any better way to handle removing elements from dynamic arrays? I'm new to C and I couldn't find anything useful on the internet. Thanks :)

Comment: Strong advice to use unsigned types (preferrably size_t) for sizes and indexes.

Comment: @RandomDavis that's the answer I derived my code from, but I fear this method causes the segfault. Do you think the segfault's origin is probably not in this function? Should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Your code looks correct and it's hard to make it simpler and more efficient. The problem is elsewhere and it can be anything. You could start checking if index is between 0 and size-1. If it's not, then there is a problem somewhere in the calling code.

Comment: Okay, i'm glad to hear that. I will try to find my error elsewhere then.

Comment: Evaluation of `toMove * sizeof(array[0])` will yield an integer expression. Using size_t could avoid this.

Comment: @user3121023 good point for the potential leak of `array[index]`, but there won't be any duplicates, we just move the pointers. Why _potentiel_? Because we don't know what those pointer _actually_ are, they could point on memory that has not been allocated via malloc.

Comment: @user3121023 yes, but [9] will be garbage (and incidentally the same as [8]). If you cleanup [9] you'll cleanup [8] as well and then you'll have pointers on freed memory in [8]